# Design Pattern in CellPaiting of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am learning Design Pattern in .NET. I want to know the type of Design Pattern is used in CellPainting of DataGridView.

In DataGridView, you can define type of DataGridViewColumn you want, example: DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, DataGridViewLinkColumn, ...

DataGridView has a method CellPainting, which can paint a Cell based on type of column. Example: If cell is in a DataGridViewLinkColumn, this cell will be painted like a link (text is underline, text color is blue, ...).

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following help?
[How to: Customize the Appearance of Cells in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hta8z9sz.aspx)

Comment: I want to know which design pattern is applied in DataGridView.